# Apache Camel - aggregate messages based on body

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I'm currently using apache camel to consume SQS messages and everything has been working fine.

As part of one project, I consume S3 notification events when a file is uploaded. The files are uploaded to a predicable S3 key - `(<type>/<account-id>/<id>/<file>)`.

When processing, I am using camel to aggregate messages into a single exchange (wait for either 10 messages, or timeout after 1 second). I was wondering but, is there a way to aggregate based on the S3 - for example, aggregate messages that have the same type, or id.

From what I understand from reading the camel documentation, there are ways to query Json payloads or header values - is this a possible approach (since the S3 event notification is a Json message, and according to the AWS documention a PUT operation would only generate a single record entry)? Or would I need to implement my own Aggregator?

To add a bit of context - I have a service which collects data, and uploads the data to S3. Another service will then download this data when notified, process it and uploads to another bucket. If I can aggregate S3 notifications, I am able to combine data and upload it, cutting down on the amount of uploads and API calls etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [camel-aws s3](http://camel.apache.org/aws-s3.html) component then you can access/get the S3 key from the Message's `CamelAwsS3Key` header and you don't need to query the body, but you need to extract the required field from the S3 key.

Comment: Yeah I had checked out the s3 component, the issues I had were I can't delete the processed file (other apps might need it), and needing to keep track of which files had already been processed after polling

Comment: There is a parameter for this component to disable the deletion of the processed file: `deleteAfterRead=false`. What do you mean by "needing to keep track of which files had already been processed"? If you mean to filter out duplicates then you can use an [idempotent repository](http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html) with the `CamelAwsS3Key` as the key.

Comment: Yeah the files would be kept for backup and for other apps to process - the repository looks like a solution but I am trying to avoid additional infrastructure etc and would be worried about performance over time. If there was no need to keep the files this would probably be the best solution (since I'm already using camel for SQS I've some experience as well which is a bonus).

Answer (score 0):

While not the best or most generic solution, I did find a way to get this working -

I simply added a additional Processor that gets invoked before passing to the aggregator. The processor simply checks the event record (since I am listening for PUT events from S3, according to the AWS docs there should only be one record) for the S3 key and sets the headers on the Message.

The Aggregator is then able to combine Exchanges based on these headers (simply *S3-Type*, *S3-Account-Id*, and *S3-Id*).